# How to change sites,newsfeed,skydrive url?

Tags: user-profile, newsfeed

personal sites, newsfeed and skydrive on the top bar to the right point to site collections on a webapplication on port 8001.

I would like them to be on another web applcation on port 8005. 
I have created new site collection (and a new user profile service applcation) to host them but I don't know how to make them point to 8005.

Do you know how could I make this change?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you are using PORTS on your My Sites? I have found that this really confuses Users.

Comment: actually there is an AAM, so they don't see the port

Comment: OK, I was just wondering why use the port in the first place and avoid the AAM. Glad it's working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in to Central Administration -> Manage Service Application -> User Profile Service Application.

Under "My Site Settings" you have "Setup My Site", in here you can update the value for "My Site Host Location" to match your new setup. Make sure to click "OK" at the bottom.

Not sure if this goes through immediately or if there are some timer jobs that need to run before the changes will be visible in the GUI for your users.

Comment: No worries, glad to help!